# LoRa inventory application

Tags: lora, bluetooth

As far as I know there is no smartphone with Lora builtin compatibility.
I'm looking if I can build a inventory solution based on LoRa.
Until today the solution was to use the NarrowBand (deprecated in our location) technology with a bar code reader plugged to a PDA NarrowBand compatible. I'm looking for a similar system.

- Is there smartphone with LoRa I'm not aware of?
- Is there "wearable" Bluetooth-LoRa gateways (or similar)?

I can't use WiFi to cover the stockyard.

Comment: Is this indoors or outdoors? What kind of distances are you considering? LoRa can have tremendous range outdoors, but indoors it can be anything from good to horrible. Also what region are you in, and how many readings are you expecting to do? In some regions the duty cycle limits are quite low.

Comment: It is outdoor, essentially stack of wood (that's why WiFi is bad). 1km max. France. 5k elements to scan by a group of 5 devices. 1 scan every 5s at max.

Comment: For the rnage I already test with a temperature sensor and it works just fine. I'm in a RD process if you have a better solution tell me.

Comment: There’s no magic, something which interferes with Wi-Fi will interfere with any other radio technology including LoRa. Line of sight is king. Depending on the layout you lay be better if with strategically placed Wi-Fi APs (e.g if you have long straight alleys between the stacks, placing the APs nearly aligned in the alleys would give you decent coverage along each of those alleys), but that may require a lot of hardware.

Comment: 1 frame every 5 seconds is about the maximum you can do over LoRa in France, without ACKs, small payloads, and the fastest data rate (shortest range, in theory). It would probably require quite a bit of testing to ensure it meets your requirements.

Comment: 1km is if I only set one antenna (worst scenario tested). I can set two more antennas which reduce range to 300m max. As I said WiFi is not a option even a mesh network is too complicated to build in this configuration

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are no smartphones with built-in LoRa modem. However, there are several LoRaWAN trackers on the market that can scan for Bluetooth Beacons in the neighborhood, and transmit the result of the scan (a list of beacon IDs) together withe the location coordinates to a central application server via LoRaWAN. These devices can be considered as "a kind of" *BLE to LoRa gateways* too. Some of these devices are wearables.

An example of such warable is: the [Abeeway Smart Badge](https://www.abeeway.com/smart-badge/).  If you dont need a wearable device, you can also check the [Abeeway Compact Tracker](https://www.abeeway.com/compact-tracker/) that offers a very long (several years) battery life time.

With such devices, your warehouse solution would work in the following way:

- Instead of bar codes, you will equip your assets with BLE beacons
  (You can find hundreds of cheap beacons on the Internet (e.g.: at https://www.aliexpress.com/)
- You use a special LoRaWAN end device (tracker) to detect the proximity of the beacons and send their IDs (and optionally their locations) via LoRaWAN to the backend.